# sfGuard token login not working in Symfony 1

Tags: symfony1, sfguard

I'm having issues getting `sfGuard` token login working with a Symfony app. The Symfony app is accessed through WordPress plugin. The WordPress plugin is bare bones which embeds a `iframe` with a token string in the WP control panel:

```
<iframe src="/app/index.php/api/authenticate/**token**" width="100%" height="100%">
```

This works fine on the live server. After digging through my error logs I found this:

```
PDO Connection Error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES), referer: http://****/wp-admin/admin.php?page=custom-sms.php 
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/sfapp/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/storage/sfPDOSessionStorage.class.php on line 162, referer: http://****/wp-admin/admin.php?page=custom-sms.php
```

The odd thing is though I'm able to write/connect to the database on the front-end of the site. What could be causing the app not to use the database username and password set in the `database.yml` config file?

The `app.yml` file:

```
all:
  security:
    #to auto-login to the SMS alert system from inside Wordpress admin
    token: **token**
    username: user@web.com
```

BTW, I've never used Symfony before and I inherited this site with no documentation.

### Update

`database.yml` file:

```
# You can find more information about this file on the symfony website:
# http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/07-Databases

all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn:      mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name
      username: **username**
      password: **password**
```

### 2nd Update:

To add, I manually set the `$env` variable to `prod` for testing `/web/index.php` on the new server.

`factories.yml` file:

```
# You can find more information about this file on the symfony website:
# http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/05-Factories

prod:
  logger:
    class: sfAggregateLogger
    param:
      level: err
      loggers:
        sf_file_debug:
          class: sfFileLogger
          param:
            level: err
            file: %SF_LOG_DIR%/%SF_APP%_%SF_ENVIRONMENT%.log

staging:
  logger:
    class: sfAggregateLogger
    param:
      level: notice
      loggers:
        sf_file_debug:
          class: sfFileLogger
          param:
            level: notice
            file: %SF_LOG_DIR%/%SF_APP%_%SF_ENVIRONMENT%.log

test:
  storage:
    class: sfSessionTestStorage
    param:
      session_path: %SF_TEST_CACHE_DIR%/sessions

  response:
    class: sfWebResponse
    param:
      send_http_headers: false

  mailer:
    param:
      delivery_strategy: none

all:
  routing:
    class: sfPatternRouting
    param:
      generate_shortest_url:            true
      extra_parameters_as_query_string: true

  view_cache_manager:
    class: sfViewCacheManager
    param:
      cache_key_use_vary_headers: true
      cache_key_use_host_name:    true
```

Comment: Show us the `config/databases.yml` file.

Comment: Just updated! Thanks for the help

Comment: and what do you have inside the `apps/[yourapp]/config/factories.yml`?

Comment: I don't see any use of `sfPDOSessionStorage` to manage your session. It seems that your error come from this class which is normal defined inside the factories.yml. Do you have an other app for this symfony instance? Like the backend or watherver that can use `sfPDOSessionStorage` as session storage? Search on your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. All credit goes to @j0k for the pointers.

During setup on the new server I was hitting some errors with the session storage, so I changed the storage class type on the `[app]/config/factories.yml` to `sfNoStorage`. Reverting back to `sfPDOSessionStorage` allows the token login to work.

```
all:
  storage:
    #http://www.designdisclosure.com/2009/11/symfony-doctrine-database-session-storage/
    class: sfPDOSessionStorage
    param:
      session_name: ugro
      database: doctrine
      db_table: session
      db_id_col: sess_id
      db_data_col: sess_data
      db_time_col: sess_time
```